# LinkedIn returns different share count when a lidc cookie is set

Tags: cookies, share, linkedin-api

I used this URL here to get the share count of a URL

https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://google.de&format=json

```
{
    "count": 83,
    "fCnt": "83",
    "fCntPlusOne": "84",
    "url": "http://google.de"
}
```

However, when I use PHP & cURL to get the share count with the same URL, I get this

```
{
    "count": 2285,
    "fCnt": "2,285",
    "fCntPlusOne": "2,286",
    "url": "http://google.de"
}
```

When disabling cookies in the WebDeveloper addon, or using another Browser, I'm getting the correct(?) count.

When I delete the cookie `lidc` from the cookies of LinkedIn I get the correct count, too.

So basically, my question is, why does the share count differ? Which one is the correct one? For me, it looks like the second result is the correct one.